# How can print my variables summary outputs with for loop in R

Tags: r

I use summary() function to see which variables get what value. For example I have 10 variables in my data. ( v1, v2, v3,...,v10) This is the output I want it to write for each variables in for loop.

First variable is "v1", "3" is minimum, "9" is maximum and "5.6" is mean for "v1".
Second variable is "v2", "6.2" is minimum, "15.3" is maximum and "8.9" is mean for "v1".
.
.
Tenth variable is "v10" ...

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: i dont know how to coding this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in a loop :

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(V1 = rnorm(5), V2 = rnorm(5), V3 = rnorm(5))
cols <- names(df)

for (i in seq_along(df)) {
  cat(sprintf("\nVariable %d is %s, it's minimum is %.2f, maximum is %.2f and mean is %.2f",
          i, cols[i], min(df[[i]], na.rm = TRUE), max(df[[i]], na.rm = TRUE), mean(df[[i]], na.rm = TRUE)))
}

#Variable 1 is V1, it's minimum is -0.56, maximum is 1.56 and mean is 0.19
#Variable 2 is V2, it's minimum is -1.27, maximum is 1.72 and mean is -0.04
#Variable 3 is V3, it's minimum is -0.56, maximum is 1.22 and mean is 0.31
```